# ServiceBusConnectionException - Receive Transport faulted

Tags: c#, azure, masstransit

I have the following error when I start the masstransit with azure `bus.Start();` on my function `StartService()` I have configuring my azure with masstransit and autofact. The error:

```
MassTransit.Azure.ServiceBus.Core.ServiceBusConnectionException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=ReceiveTransport faulted: sb://softbaire-amilkar.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=**REMOVED**;SharedAccessKey=**REMOVED**/TeamTimeManager
  Source=mscorlib
```

configuration with masstransit:

```
public static IContainer ConfigureContainer()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    builder.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();

        cfg.AddConsumer<TeamTimeManager>();

        cfg.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, conf) =>
        {
            var settings = new HostSettings
            {
                ServiceUri = new Uri("sb://softbaire-amilkar.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=UeIC0z5RPCt25SjnWdss2ssP5a6msUKNJxmLnBpm26g="),
                TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateManagedIdentityTokenProvider()
            };

            conf.Host(settings);

            conf.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
        });
    });

    return builder.Build();
}
```

this is where I start the service and I get the error:

```
public void StartService()
{
    var container = CreatorContainer.ConfigureContainer();
    var bus = container.Resolve<IBusControl>();

    if (host != null)
    {
        host.Close();
    }

    host = new ServiceHost(typeof(TeamTimeManager));
    utilHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(TeamTimeUtilityManager));

    bus.Start();
    source.TraceInformation("Starting TeamTimeManager Azure Bus...");

    host.Open();
    source.TraceInformation("TeamTimeManager Started!");

    utilHost.Open();
    utilSource.TraceInformation("Starting TeamTimeUtilityManager...");
}
```

**UPDATE**

this problem is solved when I comment on the line:

```
cfg.AddConsumer<TeamTimeManager>();
```

if I add a queue or a subscription the problem appears again

**BUG**

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/issues/8627

Comment: I removed your Shared Access Token, I'd suggest going into the Azure Portal and recreating the Shared Access Key since you posted it on a public forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was in the token provider.

The problem was that the token generated was connected to azure but without any queue or topic register, the problem started when I wanted to register queues and topics, when I wanted to generate the connection with the queue or a topic I got an error because the token was invalid for my user(weird), so... I changed the method to generate the token and everything started to work correctly.

**Before:**

```
var settings = new HostSettings
{
   ServiceUri = new Uri("sb://xxxx-busazure.servicebus.windows.net"),
   TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateManagedIdentityTokenProvider()
};
```

**After:** now I'm using `CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider()` you need to send as parameters the "SharedAccessKeyName" and the "SharedAccessKey"

```
var settings = new HostSettings
{
   ServiceUri = new Uri("sb://xxxxx-busazure.servicebus.windows.net"),
   TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("RootManageSharedAccessKey", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx=")
};
```

queues and everything is running smoothly, Final configuration method:

```
        public static IContainer ConfigureContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.AddMassTransit(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.SetKebabCaseEndpointNameFormatter();
                cfg.AddServiceBusMessageScheduler();

                cfg.AddConsumer<TeamTimeManager>();
                
                cfg.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, conf) =>
                {
                    conf.UseServiceBusMessageScheduler();

                    var settings = new HostSettings
                    {
                       ServiceUri = new Uri("sb://amilkar-busazure.servicebus.windows.net"),
                       TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateSharedAccessSignatureTokenProvider("RootManageSharedAccessKey", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
                    };
                    conf.Host(settings);

                    conf.ReceiveEndpoint("team-time-manager", e =>
                    {
                        e.ConfigureConsumer<TeamTimeManager>(context);
                    });

                    conf.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });

            });

            return builder.Build();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's likely permissions. MassTransit requires Manage, and you're configuring the managed identity token provider.

1. Remove the shared access credentials from the connection string, since they would conflict with the managed identity provider.
2. Make sure the service identity has Manage permissions on the namespace.